# Exportar datos en diferentes hojas de excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, maatwebsite

El problema es el siguiente estoy intentando exportar los datos de una tabla según el mes que introduzca el usuario, lo que he realizado funciona pero estaba pensando de que si existiera una manera de realizar el mismo procedimiento y pero en otra hoja del excel con otra tabla, las columnas serian las mismas añadiendo una columna de `num_asoc`. Estoy usando `laravel 8` y `maatwebsite excel`, soy nuevo usando las consultas de laravel y desconozco si me es posible usar codigo `sql` para relacionar la fecha de ambas tablas y usar algun metodo para separar los resultados en diferentes hojas. (Espero haberme explicado bien)

Codigo Tabla A.

```
public function query()
{   
    return Arrendamiento::whereMonth('fecha', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->date)->format('m'))->select(['nombre', 'cantidad']);
}
```

Codigo Tabla B.

```
public function query()
{   
    return Aportes::whereMonth('fecha', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->date)->format('m'))->select(['num_asoc','nombre', 'cantidad']);
}
```

Comment: O sea, ¿que consulta en crudo quieres usar? recuerda que tienes a tu disposición [`DB::raw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions) pero danos un ejemplo mas claro para ver si hay una mejor solución

Comment: la consulta que pensaba usar era `SELECT arrendamientos.nombre, arrendamientos.cantidad, aportaciones.numero_asociado,aportaciones.nombre,aportaciones.cantidad
FROM arrendamientos
INNER JOIN aportaciones
ON MONTH(arrendamientos.fecha) = MONTH(aportaciones.fecha)
WHERE MONTH(arrendamientos.fecha) = ?` de esta forma me trae los datos que quiero pero me los agruparia en un solo excel, y lo que quiero seria traer los datos pero separar los de la tabla A en la hoja 1 y los datos de la tabla B en la hoja 2

Comment: Okey, usas **eloquent** verdad, ¿supongo que estas tablas están relacionadas? de alguna u otra manera es necesario para poder hacer un `JOIN`

Comment: Pues lastimosamente no están relacionadas, entonces no será posible lo que deseo hacer.

Comment: Claro que hay alternativas, veré si se me ocurre algo...